Keycloak: How to validate JWT token between 2 differents realm/client
i have a ‘test’ realm on keycloak version 21.1, this realm has a ‘test client’ client which is used by a c# backend which exposes some api. this backend authenticates to keycloak with this realm and client. I then have a frontend app, but it uses the ‘test 2’ realm with the ‘test 2’ client, so when I login I am given a jwt token generated by this client. Now I need from my frontend app to call the backend api, the problem is that they use different realms and clients to authenticate, so the token that is passed from the frontend (generated by the test 2 client) is not recognised by the test realm and test client and I get an error. Instead I need the two to be able to communicate, so that the realm test correctly validates the token it receives from test 2, how do I do that?
I have tried creating a ‘keycloak opeid connect’ in the ‘test’ realm by pointing it to the ‘test 2’ realm but this does not seem to be enough to solve the problem
